# Как лучше сделать переход на другую страницу с точки зрения безопасности?

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap, безопасность

Пишу приложение используя WebAPI2, C#, AngularJS,и Bootstrap и почти сразу возник вопрос при применении стилей Bootstrap, сейчас ссылки на страницы выглядят так:

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#videos">Videos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#photos">Photos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#audios">Audios</a></li>
                <li><a href="#biography">Biography</a></li>
                <li><a href="#books">Books</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Можно использовать **ng-click** и в каком-нибудь методе производить переход на другую страницу с помощью `$location.path('/video')`.

Как будет лучше?
Буду очень признателен за ссылки на ресурсы с информацией по улучшению безопасности своих приложений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> а можно использовать ng-click и в каком-нибудь методе производить переход на другую страницу с помощью $location.path('/video').

Можно. Все зависит от ситуации. Если вам нужно перейти на другую страницу перед тем выполнив какие-то действия, то лучше делать ng-click, а потом редирект на другую страницу, а вот если просто перейти, то пусть будет ссылка.
Вот вам ссылка на официальную документацию по безопасности angular [security](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/security)